# Pyparsing indentedBlock

Tags: pyparsing

I'm trying to use the "indentedBlock" based on the following code:

```
import pyparsing as pp
import pprint

class Parser(object):
def __init__(self):
    indentStack = [1]
    stmt = pp.Forward()
    start = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "/" + "\." + "-" + ":" + "!" + "*"+" ")
    funcDecl = (pp.OneOrMore(start)+ pp.restOfLine)
    func_body = pp.indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
    funcDef = pp.Group(funcDecl + func_body)
    stmt << (funcDef)
    self.__parser = pp.OneOrMore(stmt)

def parse(self, line):
    try:
        res = self.__parser.parseString(line)
        pprint.pprint(res)
        print("done")
    except pp.ParseException as x:
        print(x)
```

After applaying i got the following error:

Expected W:(ABCD...) (at char 226), (line:6, col:37)

The main look like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
parser = Parser()

test = """first level config parameter 1-n
 second level config parameter 1-n
  thirt level config parameter 1-n
 second level config parameter 1-n
  thirt level  config parameter 1-n
first level config parameter 1-n"""

print(test)
parser.parse(test)
```

Any ideas what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace-sensitive parsing is always a challenge with pyparsing, given its default behavior of skipping over whitespace. In addition, defining an expression as a `Word` whose valid characters include `' '` is usually asking for trouble. But since this is being wrapped in an `indentedBlock` (which will take care of looking for newlines in the right places), you might get away with it here.

I expanded your test string to include some blank lines and some multiple line blocks, and came up with this:

```
import pyparsing as pp

test = """\
first level config parameter 1-n
 second level config parameter 1-n

  thirt level config parameter 1-n
  thirt level config parameter n+1-m

 second level config parameter 1-n
  thirt level  config parameter 1-n
first level config parameter 1-n"""

import pyparsing as pp

indent_stack = [1]
func_body = pp.Forward()
# what you had as `start` looks like pretty much just any line of characters
stmt = pp.Word(pp.printables + " ")
func_body <<= pp.Group(stmt + pp.indentedBlock(func_body | stmt, indent_stack))

# parse your sample text and output results with pprint
pp.OneOrMore(func_body | pp.Group(stmt)).parseString(test).pprint()
```

Gives:

```
[['first level config parameter 1-n',
  [[['second level config parameter 1-n',
     [['thirt level config parameter 1-n'],
      ['thirt level config parameter n+1-m']]]],
   [['second level config parameter 1-n',
     [['thirt level  config parameter 1-n']]]]]],
 ['first level config parameter 1-n']]
```